# Error #1034: cannot convert XMLList@c093fd1 to mx.collections.ArrayCollection

Tags: xml, apache-flex

```
        protected function initView(event:ViewNavigatorEvent):void
            {
                // Api Call
                NFLScore.url="http://api.nfldata.apiphany.com/trial/XML/ScoresByWeek/2013REG/14" +
                    "?key=BDAE4263-4522-45B9-96FF-01F0DFB0F610";
                NFLScore.send();
            }
            protected function NFLScore_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
            {
                // Alle items en Labels value geven

                myData=event.result.ArrayOfScore.Score;

            }
            protected function NFLScore_faultHandler(event:FaultEvent):void
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                printUit.text = "foute zoek opdracht";
            }

                                //////// End ////////
            ///////////////////////// API CALL /////////////////////////

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
        <s:HTTPService id="NFLScore" fault="NFLScore_faultHandler(event)" 
                       result="NFLScore_resultHandler(event)" resultFormat="e4x" />
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:actionContent>
        <s:Button id="Score" icon="assets/Score.png" click="Score_clickHandler(event)" />
    </s:actionContent>

    <s:Label id="printUit"/>
    <s:TextArea height="100%" width="100%" id="txtResult" text="{NFLScore.lastResult.Score.AwayScore}"/>


</s:View>

Result: 

<AwayScore xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">20</AwayScore>
<AwayScore xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">26</AwayScore>
<AwayScore xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">21</AwayScore>
```

Want:
output:
20
26
21

Situation: I'm calling on API that gives me result (XML) as main node ArrayOfScore after that Score where the date is that i want. But i keep getting error "TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert XMLList@c1e1fd1 to mx.collections.ArrayCollection. "

Comment: What is `myData` defined as?  Is your error being triggered by the binding on the TextArea or inside `NFLScore_resultHandler`?

Comment: I don't anticipate that you'd be able to cast an XMLList to an ArrayCollection.  Have you tried an XMLListCollection instead?

Answer (score 0):

You have to rewrite the code as specified below

```
protected function NFLScore_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
            {
                var obj:SomeObject = null;//someobject is any class that stores the xml data that is returned from the server. 
                for(XML item:event.result.ArrayOfScore.Score){
                      obj = new SomeObject();
                      obj.someProperty = item.toString();
                      myData.additem(obj);
                }
            }
```

Basically what you are doing is, converting one object(xmllist) type into arraycollection object by the above iteration. This may not be perfect but, shoudl give you an idea to start working on it.